# The largest group acting on a non-orientable surface of genus 5

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, mapping-class-groups, surfaces

Let $N_5$ denote the non-orientable surface of genus 5.

In Conder's database [https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~conder/BigSurfaceActions-Genus2to101-ByGenus.txt](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Econder/BigSurfaceActions-Genus2to101-ByGenus.txt) we can see that the biggest finite group $F$ acting on $N_5$ has order 120. Moreover, the quotient has signature $(0; +; [-]; \{(2,4,5)\})$.

Is there a very concrete description of this group $F$?

To be even more concrete. I would like to the length $n$ of the largest chain of subgroups $1=F_0<F_1<\cdots< F_n=F$ of $F$. Since $120=(2^3)(3)(5)$ then $n\leq 5$. Is it $n=5$? Is $n$ strictly less than 5?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the notation well enough to answer your first question.  As to the second, it seems to me that, no matter which group on the genus 5 list one considers, the only possible composition factors are groups of prime order and the alternating group $A_5$.  As $A_5$ has a chain $1<Z_2<Z_2 \times Z_2<A_4<A_5$, it follows that every one of the groups in question has a chain of subgroups that is as long as Lagrange's Theorem will allow.

Comment: Eventually it's just a basic question about a certain group of order 120, which you should make more explicit, but actually from John Shareshian's answer, it follows that every group of order 120 has a chain of the largest possible size (as it's always true for solvable groups, and for $A_5$).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The group $F$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_5$.

In fact, since $N_5$ is non-orientable of genus $5$, both $F$ and the extended group $F^*$ (of order twice the order of $F$) act on its orientable double cover, that has genus $4$. In Conder's database, this is expressed by saying that the action of $F$ in genus $4$ is reflexible and that there is a non-orientable quotient.

Looking at the actions of groups of order $120$ on orientable surfaces of genus $4$ that have these properties, we can find the presentation of $F$; in fact, there is a unique such a group:

[image]

Now a simple computation with GAP4 does the job.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Francesco. Your answer is exactly the kind of answer I was expecting.